# How do I merge two SQL Server table columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table `Brands` (concerned column is `BrandName`) and `Products` (concerned column is `ProductName`). How do I merge these two columns so the structure of result of the select statement would be

```
BrandName - ProductName
```

e.g.: if `BrandName` is "Campbell" and product name is "New England Chowder", the `select` statement should return

```
Campbell - New England Chowder
```

Here is the structure of `Products`

```
SKU int PK 
ProdName char(10) 
Description varchar(max) 
BrandID int (FK) ... etc with other columns
```

Here is the `Brands` structure

```
BrandID int PK 
BrandName char(20) 
Logo varbinary
```

Comment: Please show sample data and the structure of the two tables.

Comment: You can share the structure of your database here: http://schemadeck.com/zqzzn6

Comment: Don't use `CHAR(n)` for any string of 10 or more characters of variable length - use `VARCHAR(n)` instead. I'd recommend using `CHAR(n)` only for string of max. 3-5 chars that are all the same length, e.g. ISO country codes (`USA`, `GER` etc.) or ISO currency codes or something like that - but never for anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be this query - a simple join between the 2 tables and concatenation of the names. I also used `RTRIM` function to remove extra spaces as you're using `char` data type.

```
SELECT RTRIM(b.BrandName) + ' - ' + RTRIM(p.ProductName)
FROM Brands b
INNER JOIN Products p ON b.BrandID = p.BrandID
```